# Delegate inheritance explanation

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

I understand that an action is just a pre-declared delegate that can accept a single parameter of the type defined. so `Action<String>` represents a method that has no return and accepts a single string parameter. So far so good.

In my code i have this method:

```
public void Send<TMessageType>(Types.MessageBase<TMessageType> message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");
            List<Delegate> subscriptions;
            if (register.TryGetValue(typeof(TMessageType), out subscriptions))
            {
                foreach (Delegate subscription in subscriptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoking....");
                    subscription.DynamicInvoke(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

All of the Delegates in the subscriptions variable were actually instantiated as actions. My question is, why does my code work? Why dont i need to cast my delegate back into an action (it would be `Action<TMessageType>`), before i can use it? surely the default delegate type has no idea what parameters to expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the short answer is because your call to `DynamicInvoke` is a late-bound call and doesn't actually know whether or not it *even needs* parameters.

**[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx)**

> Dynamically invokes (late-bound) the method represented by the current delegate.

As a side note:
Given that you have knowledge of the type being passed to the `Action` you should probably refactor your code to directly invoke the actions and not use `DynamicInvoke` if you can avoid it as there will be a performance impact. If you cannot avoid it due to restrictions not shown then so be it.

```
        List<Action<Types.MessageBase<TMessageType>>> subscriptions;
        if (register.TryGetValue(typeof(TMessageType), out subscriptions))
        {
            foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invoking....");
                subscription(message);
            }
        }
```

Of course I don't know what would be involved in refactoring the `TryGetValue` call.

Answer (score 1):

no it does not know and doesn't care - it takes a bunch of "object"-parameters and calls your action with it. It is not checked at compiletime but at runtime  - [see here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `DynamicInvoke`, which, as its name implies, invokes dynamically the delegate. It's an order of magnitude slower then `Invoke` but is able to match automatically the parameter type, at runtime rather than relying on compile time information.